# Why does this code not work?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE TABLE  `mydb`.`Height` (
  `Height ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Value` DOUBLE NULL ,
  `Unit` VARCHAR(10) not NULL ,
  `Value in Cms` DOUBLE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Height ID`))
;

CREATE TABLE  `mydb`.`HeightUnit` (
    `Unit` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL ,
    `Size in Cms` DOUBLE NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY (`Unit`),

    FOREIGN KEY (`Unit`)
        REFERENCES `Height` (`Unit`)
        ON DELETE NO ACTION
        ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
;
```

I get a 1005 cant create table errno 150...

Comment: A FK needs to reference  a PK.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced column needs to have an index.

```
CREATE TABLE  `mydb`.`Height` (
  `Height ID` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `Value` DOUBLE NULL ,
  `Unit` VARCHAR(10) not NULL ,
  `Value in Cms` DOUBLE NULL ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Height ID`),
  INDEX (`Unit`))
;
```

Usually a foreign key should reference the primary key of the other table. Are you sure you want to reference the `Height` column rather than `Height ID`?

Comment: The second table (Height Unit) contains the Unit of Height like Cm, Inches, etc..... Which the 1st table should lookup